# inherit from string in c++

Tags: c++, string, inheritance

I'm reading thinking in c++. I'm confused by the following code fragment showed in that book.

```
class MyString: public string, public Object {
public:
  ~MyString() {
    cout << "deleting string: " << *this << endl;
  }
  MyString(string s) : string(s) {}
};
```

I'm confused by `*this`. `this` is a pointer points to a MyString object itself.
Why is `*this` dereferenced as the initializing string?
To make my question more clearly, I'll give an example:

```
Mystring* x = new string("Hello");
delete x;
```

I don't list the complete code. if running the complete code, the output is:

> deleting string: hello.

which means *this = "hello".

Comment: Not a good idea, and that code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Don't publicly inherit from `std::string`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Why is *this dereferenced as the initializing string?"

Comment: That is not a real question. For one, it makes no sense. What is your _actual_ question? And when will we get a code example that is valid C++? (i.e. with a constructor that fits the stated ctor args)

Comment: @NicolBolas Are you implying it's ok to inherit from `std::string` privately? I was under the impression most STL objects do not have virtual dtor in which case inheriting from them at all will probably lead to memory leaks or other undefined behavior.

Comment: @SchighSchagh, It's ok to inherit from something without a virtual destructor, but only if you know what you're doing. It's usually easier to leave it at you shouldn't ever do so.

Comment: @chris Actually, I knew that. My real question to NicolBolas is why he thinks inheriting publicly vs privately makes a difference.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: because with private inheritence, users can't upcast, so the lack of a virtual destructor is irrelevant.  (of course, if theres a member that does the upcast, it could still be a problem, but generally nobody does that)

Answer (score 0):

Because the overload of `operator <<` with `std::ostream` and `std::string` extracts and prints the `c_str()` representation of the string, or the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

this is the pointer to the current object.  *this is dereferencing the pointer to the current object which is since it derives from string a string.  The overloaded osteram operator is then invoked on.

When you derive from and object you create an is a relationship with the derived object.

Also don't derive from a std class as most don't have virtual destructors.